# Specflow stability

Tags: specflow

As the project I'm working on is growing, the number of tests is also growing. But, in my case, when the number of scenario's being tested increases, the stability of Specflow seems to be decreasing.

Let me try to clearify: When I'm running, for instance, some test lists (with 5 to 10 scenario's) in Visual Studio 2010 separately, all the scenario's are passing. However, when I'm running all the test lists at once (something like 70 scenario's total), some scenario's fail, that in the 'separate test list run' passed. When I immediately run the 'total test run' again, different scenario's fail, or sometimes all the files pass. In other words, which scenario's fail is totaly random.

Is anyone familiar with this issue and/or can enlighten me about the (what it seems to be) stability of Specflow when the number of scenario's to test is increasing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think this is a specflow issue at all, we run around 800 tests and all pass every time. What I expect is that you are getting crosstalk between your tests. IE your tests are failing because they are sharing data you arent expecting.

This is a pretty common problem.

Comment: How do you keep your 800 or so tests from crosstalking?

Comment: Almost every odd/unexpected failure I've personally experienced has been because of data sharing. I'm now quite careful to make sure that I put data for each scenario in the ScenarioContext.Current bag (which I tend to wrap with properties/methods to make the code cleaner and easier to understand) instead of using fields and properties etc on the step definition classes.

Comment: @TimothyHeyden they key is to make sure you are storing things in a scenario scoped data store (such as scenarioContext.Current as SaxonMatt has suggested). Its also important to make sure any external resources (databases/files ect) get put into a known state at the start of the test. Use [BeforeScenario] to set your tests up to a known state

Comment: I get what you're saying. But the thing is, I'm also testing certain flows of a website. So I'm using Specflow tests to fill in texboxes and see if the validation is correct, select values from dropdown boxes and see if I can get to the next step on the website. Stuff like that. The step where the tests are failing on randomly is an assert to see if certain text is available on the website so I can verify if I'm on the next step.

Comment: @TimothyHeyden - I really dislike UI automation for testing, for a couple of reasons: i) it creates test-code that is highly coupled with your UI implementation - this makes the test-code highly brittle and prone to edits every time the UI gets a few edits; ii) in theory all the business logic for logging in and validation should be contained somewhere in controller classes etc - you can target that business logic directly... it is cheaper (time) to do and offers the value you really require... if there is a bug in UI->Controller it should be obvious with UAT/Manual testing, and easy to fix